# Collapsing exons using python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I am trying to collapse exons from a file according to another file containing information on to which genes the exons belongs.

One file contains the name of the exons and what gene they correspond to.

An example:

```
Exon1 Gene4
Exon2 Gene5
Exon3 Gene8
Exon4 Gene8
```

The other file is a fast file containing the exon name and the sequence, such as:

```
>Exon1
ACGTCGATTTCGATCA
>Exon2
ACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
>Exon3
ACGTCGATTTCAGCGGATCA
>Exon4
CCCACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
```

So my goal is to output a [FASTA file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) with the gene names and the corresponding exons collapsed into one sequence (CDS). As an example:

```
>Gene4
ACGTCGATTTCGATCA
>Gene5
ACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
>Gene8
ACGTCGATTTCAGCGGATCACCCACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
```

So far I have created a dict with the gene name as key and the exon names as a list of keys as below:

```
exon_to_gene_dict = {}

with open('gene_to_exon', 'r') as file_gene, open('exon.fasta', 'r') as  file_exons: 
for line in file_gene:
    line = line.rstrip().split()
    scaffold = line[0]
    gene = line[1]
    exon_to_gene_dict.setdefault(gene, []).append(scaffold)
```

Then I created a dict with the exon id's and the corresponding sequences:

```
exon_sequence_dict = {}
with open(exons.fasta,'r') as file_exons:
for line in file_exons:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('>'):
        exon_id = line[1:]

    else:
        sequence = line

        exon_sequence_dict[exon_id] = sequence


gene_to_cds_dict = {}
for exon, seq in exon_sequence_dict.items():
    for gene_id, exon1 in gene_to_exon_dict.items():
        if exon in exon1:
            gene_to_cds_dict.setdefault(gene_id, []).append(seq)


gene_id_to_sequence =[]             
for gene_id, sequence in sorted(gene_to_cds_dict.items()):
    print(gene_id, file=f_out)
    print(''.join(sequence), file=f_out)
```

So it in the end I manage to work it out as above

The output from the example is:

```
Gene4
ACGTCGATTTCGATCA
Gene5
ACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
Gene8
ACGTCGATTTCAGCGGATCACCCACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: And the expected output...

Comment: I tried to make the expected output more clear in the Question

Comment: Thanks. It looks better now. It should be just > but something happened to the text when I just had that. This is my first question here so I appreciate comment or corrections.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like BioGeek already fixed the `>`s. If there's more to improve, [edit] your question. You can look up the syntax [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete solution, using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython). BioPython automatically takes care of [the issue that Cory Weller raised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000361/50065) (if your FASTA has sequences split over multiple lines). This solution also concatenates the sequences from the same gene into a CDS.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Seq
from collections import defaultdict

with open('gene_to_exon.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    exon_to_gene = dict(tuple(line.split()) for line in lines)

exon_records = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse('exon.fasta', 'fasta'))

gene_records = defaultdict(list)
for exon_id, record in exon_records.items():
    gene_id = exon_to_gene[exon_id]
    gene_records[gene_id].append(record)

cds_records = []
for gene_id in gene_records:
    gene_record = gene_records[gene_id][0]
    if len(gene_records[gene_id]) > 1:
        sequence = ''.join([str(gene_record.seq) for gene_record in gene_records[gene_id]])
        gene_record.seq = Seq.Seq(sequence)
    gene_record.id = gene_id
    gene_record.description = gene_id # see https://www.biostars.org/p/156428/
    cds_records.append(gene_record)


with open('output.fasta', 'w') as g:
    SeqIO.write(cds_records, g, 'fasta')
```

On your input file, this gives the result:

```
>Gene8
ACGTCGATTTCAGCGGATCACCCACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
>Gene5
ACGTCGATTTCGATCAACGTAA
>Gene4
ACGTCGATTTCGATCA
```

**Edit:** Here is also a pure Python implementation. The FASTA parsing code comes from [this code monk blog post](https://drj11.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/python-getting-fasta-with-itertools-groupby/) (and adapted for Python 3) where the author describes in detail the advantage of using `itertools.groupby` over using `for` loops.

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

def isheader(line):
    return line.startswith('>')

def aspairs(filehandle):
  for header,group in itertools.groupby(filehandle, isheader):
    if header:
      line = next(group)
      ensembl_id = line[1:].split()[0]
    else:
      sequence = ''.join(line.strip() for line in group)
      yield ensembl_id, sequence

with open('exon.fasta') as f:
    exon_records = dict(aspairs(f))

with open('gene_to_exon.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    exon_to_gene = dict(tuple(line.split()) for line in lines)

gene_records = defaultdict(str)
for exon_id, seq in exon_records.items():
    gene_id = exon_to_gene[exon_id]
    gene_records[gene_id] += seq

with open('output.fasta', 'w') as f:
    for gene_id, seq in gene_records.items():
        f.write('>{}\n{}\n'.format(gene_id, seq))
```

Comment: Thans for your answer. I prefer not using BioPython for the solution, at least whilst while still being new to python and programming.

Comment: @locoto If it you are beginner, it is easier to use libraries that decrease the number of lines, making less complex programs .... please, don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: That is true @Jose but if you are a beginner and really want to understand the underlying mechanism of the wheel. Then it is probably more useful to reinvent the wheel than to use a already existing one.

Comment: Also, one sometimes loses a lot of time trying to understand how to use a library, and that time could be better spent improving one's coding skills.

Comment: @locoto See my edit, I've added a pure Python implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have the first part down, now you need to create a dictionary linking the exon to the sequence. How you go about it depends on how your FASTA file is structured. If your FASTA file has sequences on multiple lines (e.g. a max line length of 40 characters), you'll need to find a way to concatenate them all together in your sequence dictionary. Otherwise, if all nucleotides are on a single line, you'll have an easier time. You should be able to first split by ">" and then split by newline.

```
with open('exon.fasta','r') as infile:
    exon_text = infile.read()


exon_text = exon_text.split(">")[1:]
exon_text = [x.split("\n")[0:2] for x in exon_text]

exonDict = {}

for exon in text:
    exonDict[exon[0]] = exon[1]
```

You'll now have your second dictionary with the exon name as key, and the sequence as the entry. With these two parts you should be able to iterate through and concatenate all your sequences.

Comment: How would you go about connecting the two dicts Cory ? I updated my code in the answer.